# How do you remove a period or comma from a word, then translate the word to pig latin then add the period back

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I have this line of code right now, it currently translates the normal word correctly. But I need to be able to remove a period from the end of the word, translate the word, then add the period to the end of the word.

```
def translateWordToPigLatin(word):    
    translatedWord = ""
     
    if len(word) > 0:
        # If word is a number...
        if word.isdigit():
            return word
        # end if
        # If first letter is a vowel...
        if word[0].lower() in vowels:
            # print("Word begins with a vowel.") # Do vowel stuff
            translatedWord = word + 'yay'
        else:   # If first letter is a consonant...
            # print("Word begins with a consonant.") # Do consonant stuff
            translatedWord = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        # end if
    # end if
    return translatedWord.capitalize()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

Comment: `re.sub` supports callables as a replacement

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1)** Split the parts appart

```
txt = "apple#banana#cherry#orange"
x = txt.split("#")
print(x)

>>> ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange']
```

**Step 2)** Translate the word to pig Latin

**Step 3)** Put the parts together again

```
myTuple = ("John", "Peter", "Vicky")
x = "#".join(myTuple)
print(x)

>>> John#Peter#Vicky
```